# How can i use Promise Object

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I am new to react, I have this functional component with this "characters" array with urls from an api. I want to get the "id" and "name" from json from urls and use.

```
const EpisodeInfo = (props) => {
    const {name, air_date, episode, characters} = props.episode;

    const charNames = []
    characters.forEach((c) => fetch(c)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(result => charNames.push({id: result.id, name: result.name})));

    function handle_click (ids) {

        props.searchData("character_id", "1", `${ids}`);
    }

return(
   ....
    <ul>
        {charName.forEach(c =>
           <li><a href="#" onClick={() => handle_click(c.id} className="card-text "> {c.name} </a></li>)}                         
    </ul>
```

I get promise object, how can i use this object? i tried with asycn function and Promise.all() but didn't work. How can i use correctly?

Comment: This might help you, https://codeburst.io/javascript-making-asynchronous-calls-inside-a-loop-and-pause-block-loop-execution-1cb713fbdf2d

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect hook, use Promise.all() then setCharNames(charNames)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Promise.all** for handling the asynchronous operation.
Also store the charNames array in state using **useState** and also use **UseEffect** hook to make changes in charNames